# Distance calculating from each coordinate to each coordinate

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have this data frame:

```
 ID  Latitude  Longitude
  1  29.39291  -98.50925
  2  29.39923  -98.51256
  3  29.40147  -98.51123
  4  29.38752  -98.52372
  5  29.39537  -98.50402
  6  29.39343  -98.49707
  7  29.39556  -98.53148
  8  29.39706  -98.49565
```

I want calculate the [Haversine](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) distance from each coordinate to each coordinate.
And also, find how many values smaller or equal to `0.5` in each row (excluding `0` values).

I'm using this function:

```
def haversine2(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2, to_radians=True, R = 6371):
    """

    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return R * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

Expected result:

```
 ID  Latitude  Longitude    1_Dist    2_Dist    3_Dist    4_Dist    5_Dist    6_Dist    7_Dist    8_Dist  SE_0_5
  1  29.39291  -98.50925  0.000000  0.558800  0.334307  2.442989  0.882915  2.056223  3.752787  2.295881       1
  2  29.39923  -98.51256  0.558800  0.000000  0.224503  1.884152  1.441617  2.614885  3.193814  2.854464       1
  3  29.40147  -98.51123  0.334307  0.224503  0.000000  2.108690  1.217100  2.390347  3.418271  2.629913       2
  4  29.38752  -98.52372  2.442989  1.884152  2.108690  0.000000  3.325918  4.499314  1.310145  4.738936       0
  5  29.39537  -98.50402  0.882915  1.441617  1.217100  3.325918  0.000000  1.173271  4.635576  1.412938       0
  6  29.39343  -98.49707  2.056223  2.614885  2.390347  4.499314  1.173271  0.000000  5.808935  0.239727       1
  7  29.39556  -98.53148  3.752787  3.193814  3.418271  1.310145  4.635576  5.808935  0.000000  6.048434       0
  8  29.39706  -98.49565  2.295881  2.854464  2.629913  4.738936  1.412938  0.239727  6.048434  0.000000       1
```

Comment: Did the answer help you get by? If not, please state what is lacking for you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer and my time is up, but I'm sure you can take it from here

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def cartesian(d):
    # cols = d.keys()
    d.loc[:, 'key_col'] = 1
    outer = pd.merge(d, d, on='key_col', suffixes=('', '_2')).drop('key_col', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    return outer


def haversine2(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2, to_radians=True, R = 6371):
    """

    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees or in radians)

    All (lat, lon) coordinates must have numeric dtypes and be of equal length.

    """
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return R * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def main():
        a = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                          'Latitude': [29.39291, 29.39923, 29.4014, 29.38752, 29.39537, 29.39343, 29.39556, 29.39706],
                          'Longitude': [-98.50925, -98.51256, -98.51123, -98.52372, -98.50402, -98.49707, -98.53148,
                                        -98.49565]})

        cartesian_df = cartesian(a)
        print(cartesian_df)

        func = lambda row: haversine2(row['Latitude'], row['Latitude_2'], row['Longitude'], row['Longitude_2'])
        distances_df = cartesian_df.apply(func, axis=1)
        print(distances_df)

        result = cartesian_df
        result['distances'] = distances_df
        print(result)


    main()
```

This calculates a `distances` column for each combination of inputs according to your function.

You can reformat this to your needs.

output:

> ```
>     ID  Latitude  Longitude  ID_2  Latitude_2  Longitude_2  distances
> 0    1  29.39291  -98.50925     1    29.39291    -98.50925   0.000000
> 1    1  29.39291  -98.50925     2    29.39923    -98.51256   0.772456
> 2    1  29.39291  -98.50925     3    29.40140    -98.51123   0.963335
> 3    1  29.39291  -98.50925     4    29.38752    -98.52372   1.524651
> 4    1  29.39291  -98.50925     5    29.39537    -98.50402   0.575805
> ..  ..       ...        ...   ...         ...          ...        ...
> 59   8  29.39706  -98.49565     4    29.38752    -98.52372   2.919048
> 60   8  29.39706  -98.49565     5    29.39537    -98.50402   0.832361
> 61   8  29.39706  -98.49565     6    29.39343    -98.49707   0.426437
> 62   8  29.39706  -98.49565     7    29.39556    -98.53148   3.475146
> 63   8  29.39706  -98.49565     8    29.39706    -98.49565   0.000000
> ```

---

Note: running your function on your input directly does not give your expected results. try `haversine2(29.39291, 29.39923, -98.50925, -98.51256, to_radians=True, R = 6371)` [that's ids=1, 2] and get `0.7724556421884609`